# Make slope of a sigmoid curve increase linearly

Tags: calculus, functions

Currently I have an equation:

$$
y = \frac{100}{1+100e^{-.12xl*100}*3} -0.332
$$

Where $l$ is a variable between 1-100.

Here is a visualization of the equation:

[image: Graph]

When $l$ is set to 1, that is what the graph looks like.

However, when setting it to 2, the graph drastically changes, moving the slope over by $.25$ units on the x-axis. Incrementing $l$ by 1 results in the same behavior, the slope exponentially gets closer to 0, until at $l=10$, the graph almost hits it's apex at $x=.1$. This is behavior I would like to avoid. For example, this is what the graph looks like at $l=10$. This is perfect, except this is what I would like it to look like at $l=100$.

[image]

Also, the graph doesn’t progress linearly (
sorry if this doesn’t make sense, I don’t know any other way to explain it). Half of the “movement” between $l=1-10$ is made by $l=2$:

[image]

If you put them all in one image, you see that $l=2$ is in the middle of 1-10:
(Red is 10, green is 2, blue is one):

[image]

Is there a way to make the graph's slope linearly decrease as $l$ gets closer to 100, until the slope is almost at $x=0$ at $l=100$?

Comment: I'm not understanding what your goal is beyond wanting to fit a sigmoid curve to some model.  Do you have data points you want the curve to intersect?  Talk of "moving the slope over" or making "the graph's slope linearly decrease" might be a reference to the derivative of the function or to the location of the inflection point in relation to the horizontal asymptotes.  It's better to articulate what you do want rather than emphasizing "behavior I would like to avoid."

Comment: It would help if you [edit] the question to show us a picture of what you do and don't want as $t$ varies. You may not be able to accomplish that by varying this equation.

Comment: @EthanBolker I edited my question. Thanks :)

Comment: @hardmath The question has been edited. I don’t want this graph to match data points, I would like this slope to “move” (for lack of a technical term) linearly as demonstrated in the pictures where $l = 2$ and 1 and 10. Basically, $l=2$ takes up half of the motion, and from their it moves incrementally less, in a parabolic trend. Is their any way to change that?

Comment: The last sentence still makes no sense. You can't have $1$ approach $100$ .or a slope almost at $x=0$. If you [edit] to draw us a picture of _what you want_ (not what doesn't work) we may be able to help.

Comment: I think you want to make the [inflection point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point) of the sigmoid curve move in a different way than it does now, with reducing the parameter $\ell$.  Probably what you want is to rewrite your equation, replacing the way $\ell$ appears now with some more complicated factor.  However it is unclear what your goal is.  Apparently you want to keep some parameter there in the equation but get it to change the curve in a way that is easier for you to anticipate.  We can help you do that, but a more precise goal is needed.

Comment: @hardmath sorry if I'm unclear. My goal is to have $l=100$ look like it does in [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nwIXR.jpg) where $l=10$. However, if you look at [this desmos graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4bcpl6brhg), and click the play button next to the $l=1$, you should see that the curve's slope changes drastically between $l=1-5$, but after that it makes small changes. Each increment of $l$ between 1 and 100 should displace the curve evenly from x=.5 depending on the value of $l$, so at $l=50$ the "center" of the curve should be around $x=.25$.

Comment: @EthanBolker sorry, at the last sentence I meant as $l$ approaches 100. I edited it again.

Comment: @EthanBolker also read my comment to hardmath above, I hope I explained it better. Thanks so much.

Comment: To change the rate at which varying the value of $x$ changes the rate at which the curve "moves left" try replacing $x$ by $x^s$. I looked at $s=2$. $s$ does not need to be an integer. $2.5$ would work. If you want to change the rate the other way try $s$ between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for commenting! If you think you have an answer, please add it. Thanks. (a desmos graph would be appreciated)

Comment: Please draw the curves that you *would like* to have.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy Thanks for commenting. The problem is that I can get the curves I want, which is displayed at $l=10$, except their are 2 problems with this: 1) I want the curve at $l=100$ to look like the curve at $l=10$. 2) When changing $l$, the behavior is odd. I would expect $l=50$ to be “half” of the movement between $l=1$ and $l=100$. However, $l=2$ is what I would like $l=50$ to look like (as you can see in my graphs). Thanks again.

Comment: "Look like" is an insufficient description. This is why a figure is needed.

Comment: @BobbyLaspy Thanks for asking! I provided a graph showing that: first graph: the correct initial graph, second graph: $l=10$, which is what I would like $l=100$ to be, third graph: showing that $l=2$ takes up half of the “movement” between $l=1$ and $l=100$, fourth graph: providing further graphs and figures which show that the change in the curve from $l=1$ and $l=10$ doesn’t change linearly or consistently, as shown how $l=2$ is halfway between $l=1$ and $l=10$. All of these are figures in my original question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Try

$$
y=\frac{100}{1+100e^{-.12xl^{a}\left(100\right)}\cdot3}-.332
$$

with a value for $a$ that works best for you.

I think $a= 0.08$ looks about right.

This begins to work since the function
$$
g(\ell) = \ell^a
$$
is steep near $\ell = 0$ when $a < 1$.

You can experiment with other similar functions if this one doesn't work well enough.

Note: "$l$" is a poor variable name. If you must have it for some reason  $\ell$ instead.

[image]

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4bcpl6brhg

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Even though this fixes my initial problem, $l=10$ should be $l=100$, the curve still “moves” in an exponential fashion, which doesn’t fix my second problem. Thanks for trying!